# Can I use named TS types in generics same as named parameters in JS?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

TS introduced default parameters types for generics in v2.3 [Generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)

So I can define a generic type as follows:

```
interface MyGenericType<T = any, U = any, V = any, W = any> { }
```

And then I can use it as follows:

```
declare const xyz: MyGenericType<any, any, any, Date>;
```

I am trying to get rid of these default types and only specify the ones I want to define by names as follows?

```
declare const xyz: MyGenericType<{ W: Date }>;
```

However that did not work as expected because `{ W: Date }` is replacing `T` the first param not replacing `W`.

Is that thing not doable in Typescript?

Is there any workarounds other than defining `any` in the generic type declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work around. You can create another interface and use it like this.

```
interface MyGenericType<T = any, U = any, V = any, W = any> { }

interface MyExtendedGenericType<W> extends MyGenericType<any, any, any, W> { }

declare const xyz: MyExtendedGenericType<Date>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Partially inferring generic type arguments is not currently possible. The discussion for this feature can be found here:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242

In there you'll also find the link to a now closed issue that discussed referring to the type arguments by name (as in your example) which was closed because this is a rather big change as it would make the name of the type argument external to the type itself, which has rather big implications.